# Запрос к BD MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть три таблицы в базе данных

cgoods содержащая данные по товару
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вторая таблица avsizes содержит id товара из таблицы товара cgoods и размеры для этого товара

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И третья таблица содержащая пол ребенка id таблицы используется в таблице cgoods для указания для какого пола подходи това

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю запрос  к базе банных чтобы получить такую выборку которая содержит 
количество товаров по всем размерам для каждого пола

если мальчики это 1 а девочки это 2 а унисекс 3
то

```
-----------------------------
sex |  sizes  |  quantity   
-----------------------------
1   |  1      |   5      
1   |  2      |   3
1   |  3      |   5
1   |  4      |   2
1   |  6      |   1
2   |  7      |   10
2   |  2      |   3
2   |  3      |   5
3   |  1      |   2
3   |  2      |   1
3   |  7      |   10
```

Делаю такой запрос

```
SELECT csex.id as sex, avsizes.sizes as size, COUNT(avsizes.prod_ref) as quantity
FROM avsizes
RIGHT JOIN cgoods ON avsizes.prod_ref = cgoods.id
RIGHT JOIN csex ON cgoods.csex = csex.id
WHERE avsizes.prod_ref IN
(SELECT cgoods.id FROM cgoods WHERE cgoods.csex IN (SELECT csex.id FROM csex))
GROUP BY avsizes.prod_ref ORDER BY sex, size LIMIT 1010
```

Что то не-то получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в запросе, нет переменной. так и должно быть?

Comment: Да так и должно быть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы делаете group by по полю, которое не должно входить в группу. В group by по хорошему должны быть включены *все* колонки, которые не участвуют в групповых функциях, типа count. Т.е. по тем колонкам в разрезе которых вы хотите получить данные.

Я так же не понял зачем вы делаете подзапрос IN, который вам вернет все записи, т.к. вы в нем берете все 3 sex которые бывают у вас в базе и выбираете по ним все записи из cgoods. Собственно это вся таблица cgoods. Кроме случая, если у вас в ней окажется некий 4й вид пола, которого не будет в справочнике, чего допускать в принципе нельзя.

И в запросе вообще не нужна таблица csex, если у вас нет необходимости выводить названия полов. id пола прекрасно получается из cgoods.

```
SELECT cgoods.csex as sex, avsizes.sizes as size, COUNT(avsizes.prod_ref) as quantity
  FROM avsizes JOIN cgoods ON avsizes.prod_ref = cgoods.id
 GROUP BY cgoods.csex,avsizes.sizes
 ORDER BY sex, size
 LIMIT 1010
```

Comment: да точно, не заметил

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! Сейчас буду вникать в суть ошибки)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT csex.id as sex, avsizes.sizes as size, COUNT(avsizes.prod_ref) as quantity
  FROM avsizes
 RIGHT JOIN cgoods ON avsizes.prod_ref = cgoods.id AND cgoods.csex IN (SELECT csex.id FROM csex)
  LEFT JOIN csex ON cgoods.csex = csex.id
 GROUP BY avsizes.prod_ref 
 ORDER BY sex, size 
 LIMIT 1010
```

или будет лучще так

```
SELECT csex.id as sex, avsizes.sizes as size, COUNT(avsizes.prod_ref) as quantity
  FROM csex 
  INNER JOIN cgoods ON cgoods.csex = csex.id
  INNER JOIN avsizes ON avsizes.prod_ref = cgoods.id
 GROUP BY avsizes.prod_ref 
 ORDER BY sex, size 
 LIMIT 1010
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,  попробовал оба ваших варианта результат тот же!! [http://s27.postimg.org/3zwmaa0xf/2016_02_16_200001.jpg]

Comment: [http://s27.postimg.org/3zwmaa0xf/2016_02_16_200001.jpg], как видно в этом скрине в результирующей таблице почему то присутствуют значения 1 | 1 | 1  вторая строка 1 | 1 | 3 далее опять  1 1 |1   по сути ведь должно тогда быть  1 | 1 | 5 то есть для пола 1 размер 1  найдено 5 , далее перепроверил по базе то в этой таблице вторая строка 1 | 1 |3  показывает правильные данный в базе действительно только 3 товара у которых есть размер 1  тогда как формируются строки 1 и 3   ??

Comment: @ConeEnoc можете предоставить данные в текстовом виде? а то трудно проверить

Comment: Да без проблем, здесь все три таблицы https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Du7v/jcRDnzbKQ